# Fill in character and numeric values with new ones

Tags: r

I'm trying to reshape my dataframe from long to wide format, and only select the data based on a particular character, although, I wish to keep the original size of the dataframe, but in places where the row belonging to the character-value is not there, then replace the numeric columns with 0, and the character with the character-value I have chosen.

For example, here's my dataset in wide format:

```
# A tibble: 34 x 13
      id lc_name                        nrow y2010 y2011 y2012 y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017 y2018 y2019
   <int> <chr>                         <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     6 pland_03_deciduous_needleleaf     1 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0    
 2     6 pland_05_mixed_forest             1 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0.125 0.125
 3     6 pland_08_woody_savanna            2 0     0     0     0     0     0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0    
 4     6 pland_09_savanna                  2 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0     0     0     0.125
 5     6 pland_09_savanna                  3 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0     0     0.125 0.125 0.125
 6     6 pland_09_savanna                  4 0     0.125 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
 7     6 pland_10_grassland                4 0.125 0     0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125
 8     6 pland_10_grassland                3 0     0     0     0     0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0     0    
 9     6 pland_10_grassland                5 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0     0     0     0    
10     6 pland_10_grassland                6 0     0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0     0     0     0     0    
# ... with 24 more rows
```

If I wanted to select all values belonging to `pland_09_savanna` then I would usually do:

```
data <- data[data$lc_name == "pland_09_savanna",
```

However, it removes the other rows. I wish to keep the other rows that are removed when selecting like above, and fill in all the other character-names in `lc_name` with `pland_09_savanna` and give all the other values `0`.

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 34 x 13
      id lc_name                        nrow y2010 y2011 y2012 y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017 y2018 y2019
   <int> <chr>                         <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     6 pland_09_savanna                  1 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
 2     6 pland_09_savanna                  1 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3     6 pland_09_savanna                  2 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
 4     6 pland_09_savanna                  2 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0     0     0     0.125
 5     6 pland_09_savanna                  3 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0     0     0     0.125 0.125 0.125
 6     6 pland_09_savanna                  4 0     0.125 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
 7     6 pland_09_savanna                  4 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8     6 pland_09_savanna                  3 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
 9     6 pland_09_savanna                  5 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
10     6 pland_09_savanna                  6 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
# ... with 24 more rows
```

reproducible code:

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L), lc_name = c("pland_03_deciduous_needleleaf", 
"pland_05_mixed_forest", "pland_08_woody_savanna", "pland_09_savanna", 
"pland_09_savanna", "pland_09_savanna", "pland_10_grassland", 
"pland_10_grassland", "pland_10_grassland", "pland_10_grassland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", 
"pland_12_cropland", "pland_12_cropland", "pland_14_mosiac"), 
    nrow = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L), y2010 = c(0.125, 
    0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0.125), y2011 = c(0.125, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 
    0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), y2012 = c(0.125, 0, 
    0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0), y2013 = c(0.125, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), y2014 = c(0.125, 0, 0, 
    0.125, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0), y2015 = c(0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), y2016 = c(0.125, 0, 
    0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0), y2017 = c(0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.125), y2018 = c(0, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0.125), y2019 = c(0, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.125, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.125)), row.names = c(NA, -34L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the selected columns which do not have `"pland_09_savanna"` value to 0 directly.

```
y_col <- grep('y\\d+', names(data))
data[data$lc_name != "pland_09_savanna", y_col] <- 0
data

# A tibble: 34 x 13
#      id lc_name                   nrow y2010 y2011 y2012 y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017 y2018 y2019
#   <int> <chr>                    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     6 pland_03_deciduous_need…     1 0     0     0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
# 2     6 pland_05_mixed_forest        1 0     0     0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
# 3     6 pland_08_woody_savanna       2 0     0     0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
# 4     6 pland_09_savanna             2 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125     0     0 0     0     0.125
# 5     6 pland_09_savanna             3 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0         0     0 0.125 0.125 0.125
# 6     6 pland_09_savanna             4 0     0.125 0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
# 7     6 pland_10_grassland           4 0     0     0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
# 8     6 pland_10_grassland           3 0     0     0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
# 9     6 pland_10_grassland           5 0     0     0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
#10     6 pland_10_grassland           6 0     0     0     0     0         0     0 0     0     0    
# … with 24 more rows
```

Comment: Then I guess I could do ```data$lc_name <- "pland_09_savanna"``` to change the names. Thanks for this. It's so simple, I missed it!